# CSS: font-weight looks like too bold in MAC browser (Chrome, Firefox)

Tags: javascript, css, browser

I know this is old problem, but I can not solve it. 
I set CSS for body tag:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

but no have any changes. It is still too bold.
Have any good ideas?

Comment: Why are you changing the font-smoothing property to fix the font-weight?

Comment: Give the font-weight as values like font-weight:400px etc like that see the link http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_font-weight&preval=900

Comment: This isn't a *problem*, this is a *choice* done by the OS